# How to display the map and mark a location in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to display a map with the current location and also draw a pin on the current location on the map. I also want to draw the line if there are multiple locations. Which is the best option for doing this on xamarin forms?

Comment: have you read the docs - this is extensively covered.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/#pins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve those requirement by using [Xamarin.forms.Maps](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.Maps/).

> display a map with the current location

**To display a map:**

Follow the steps about [Xamarin.Forms Map Initialization and Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/setup) and then you can display the map control by:

```
<ContentPage ...
             xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps">
    <maps:Map x:Name="map" />
</ContentPage>
```

You can also [display a specific location on a map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/map#display-a-specific-location-on-a-map) to show your current location.

> draw a pin on the current location on the map.

**To draw a pin:**

```
Pin pin = new Pin
{
  Label = "Santa Cruz",
  Address = "The city with a boardwalk",
  Type = PinType.Place,
  Position = new Position(36.9628066, -122.0194722)
};
map.Pins.Add(pin);
```

> draw the line if there are multiple locations

**Draw poyline:**

```
Polygon polygon = new Polygon
{
    StrokeWidth = 8,
    StrokeColor = Color.FromHex("#1BA1E2"),
    FillColor = Color.FromHex("#881BA1E2"),
    Geopath =
    {
        new Position(47.6368678, -122.137305),
        new Position(47.6368894, -122.134655),
        new Position(47.6359424, -122.134655),
        new Position(47.6359496, -122.1325521),
        new Position(47.6424124, -122.1325199),
        new Position(47.642463,  -122.1338932),
        new Position(47.6406414, -122.1344833),
        new Position(47.6384943, -122.1361248),
        new Position(47.6372943, -122.1376912)
    }
};

// add the polygon to the map's MapElements collection
map.MapElements.Add(polygon);
```

**To get current location:**

You can use [Xamarin.Essentials: Geolocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/geolocation?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android)

**Update**:

To layout the map:

```
<maps:Map x:Name="map" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Start" BackgroundColor="Red" >
    
    <maps:Map.HeightRequest>
        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Phone="100" Tablet="150" Desktop="100"/>
    </maps:Map.HeightRequest>

</maps:Map>
```

Comment: I am trying to add height to my map using the Following code ` <maps:Map.HeightRequest>
<OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
<OnIdiom.Phone>100</OnIdiom.Phone>
<OnIdiom.Tablet>150</OnIdiom.Tablet>
<OnIdiom.Desktop>100</OnIdiom.Desktop>
</OnIdiom>
</maps:Map.HeightRequest> ` but this code is not working for me.

Comment: Add VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Start" at the same time. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Shreya Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Comment: How to bind the coordinates for the map inside listview?I tried this but it is not working for me.
<maps:Map
x:Name="maps"
VerticalOptions="Start"
HorizontalOptions="End"
Margin="0,10,10,0"
MapClicked="maps_MapClicked" >
<x:Arguments>
<maps:MapSpan>
<x:Arguments>
<maps:Position>
<x:Arguments>
<x:Double>{Binding Latitude}</x:Double>
<x:Double>{Binding Longitude}</x:Double>
</x:Arguments>
</maps:Position>
<x:Double>0.01</x:Double>
<x:Double>0.01</x:Double>
</x:Arguments>
</maps:MapSpan>
</x:Arguments>
</maps:Map>